# Generalizations of the nonabelian group of order $pq$

Tags: gr.group-theory

If $p < q$ are primes then there is a nonabelian group of order $pq$ iff $q = 1 \pmod p$, in which case the group is unique. If $p = 2$ we obtain the dihedral group of order $2q$, which generalizes first to the dihedral group of order $2n$ and then even further to the "generalized dihedral group" where the cyclic group of order $n$ is replaced with any abelian group.

What if $p > 2$? Is there a natural generalization of the groups of order $pq$ to a family of groups of order $pn$? Maybe more than one possible generalization? Is it maybe even meaningful to talk about the "generalized $p$-hedral group"?

Comment: To define the generalized dihedral group , don't you need to start with an abelian group?

Comment: Sorry, yes, you're right. I've corrected the mistake above.

Comment: The group of order $pq$ is the semidirect product of $Z/p$ with $Z/q$ via the homomorphism $Z/p \to Aut(Z/q)$. The latter homomorphism also makes sense if $p,q$ are integers such that $Aut(Z/q)$ has an element of order $p$.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. So if I have a general group G such that Aut(G) has an element a of order n and define the semidirect product of Z/nZ with G via the homomorphism Z/nZ \to <a>, I suppose this is in some sense a "generalized n-hedral group". I wonder, under what conditions is such a semidirect product unique?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The nonabelian group of order $pq$ is given by generators $a$, $b$, with relations $a^p=1$, $b^q=1$, $a^{-1}ba=b^r$, where $r$ is chosen so $r^p$ is 1 mod $q$. If there is an element $r$ of order $p$ mod $n$, then there is a nonabelian group of order $pn$ with generators $a$, $b$, and relations $a^p=1$, $b^n=1$, $a^{-1}ba=b^r$.

Comment: You can even let p be composite, and choose r mod n to have order dividing p.  The groups with G' cyclic of order coprime to G/G' are given a nice description in Hall's Theory of Groups, Th 9.4.3, one of which is exactly your description.  In general, he might be interested in **metacyclic groups**, which in the finite case have a fairly similar description (King and Liebeck have some nice parameterizations of the metacyclic p-groups).